# Switching terminal character encoding while using TotalTerminal

Tags: osx-lion, terminal.app, character-encoding

I'm using the TotalTerminal 1.1.3 terminal.app plugin on Lion (10.7.1) for a visor-style terminal. TotalTerminal uses/creates a special profile which is used for every new tab opened in terminal.app. Most of the time i need UTF-8 as the character encoding, so i configured this profile to use UTF-8.

But sometimes i need to connect to a special application using telnet which outputs data using the windows latin 1 charset.

Is there a way to switch the character encoding of a terminal while it is running? Or is it possible to open a new tab in TotalTerminal using another profile?

It is possible to open another window with a different profile, but windows are lacking the visor-feature (hotkey activation, desktop overlay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to switch the character encoding of a terminal while it is running?

No. Once a terminal has been created, Terminal continues to use the same encoding for that terminal. It's possible to change the values of the locale environment variables ($LC_…) within the shell to affect the encoding used by programs invoked from the shell, but that can only affect child processes, and the Terminal application can't see those changes, so if you change them to a value that's incompatible with the original encoding used to create the terminal, text will be garbled.

> Or is it possible to open a new tab in TotalTerminal using another profile?

Not as far as I am aware. You might try asking the TotalTerminal folks or making a feature request: http://support.binaryage.com/